# Does a moped need a Carnet de Passage for Iran?

Tags: overland, iran, motorcycles, carnet-de-passage

Some countries like Iran ask for a *Carnet de Passage en Douanes* (CPD) to pass through their territories riding a vehicle. It's clear that a car or motorbike needs this CPD and that a bike not, but does a moped need a CPD?

Comment: The country that I was thinking was Iran. So I've focused on this country.

Comment: @pnuts Don't understand your comment: "is not necessarily for vehicles". Do you need the CPD for other 'objects'? For instance, I've never heard of problems by crossing a land border with a bicycle, could it be problematic?

Comment: @Ivan Bicycle maybe not (but technically it's also a vehicle ;) A more typical example would be expensive professional equipment, demonstration material for trade shows, etc.

Comment: Ok, thanks, I didn't know that CPD applies also to non-vehicle objects.

Comment: Related: http://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/193/overlanding-without-a-carnet-de-passage?rq=1

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Does a moped need a Carnet de Passage for Iran?

No, because a CPD is a bond that guarantees that duty will be paid if the object/s is/are not re-exported according to regulations. There is always the alternative of paying the duty instead. In the case of Iran and second-hand scooters the duty is 55% and there is a sales tax of 9%, so in all 68.95% of the declared value of the scooter.

There is a list of countries with CPD issuing facilities at [AIT](http://www.fia.com/international-cpd-network) where the link shown for [Spain](http://www.race.es/servicios/tramites-administrativos/carnet-de-passages) includes:

> Additionally, the issue of carnet de passages has an approximate cost of 230 euros. May vary depending on the format, 10 or 25 sheets, the printing languages ​​is French and English.
>
> The validity of this card in any of the two formats is one year.
>
> Banks usually charge a figure close to 100 euros for the issuance of the guarantee, regardless of the amount itself of it.

Comment: Yes, I know this. The 230 euros is not a problem, the problem is they ask for a bank bond for a *minimum* of 2780 euros. I've phoned them and it's independent of the value of the vehicle, you must make that minimum bond if you drive a brand new 4x4 car or if you have just bought a 20-years old second hand bike for 200 euros. It's true that you can get back your money if you come back home with the vehicle, but the idea is not come back... :/

Comment: Just a question: is there any table where I can see the value of a second hand vehicle to figure it out how I have to pay (this 68'95% of "what?")

Answer (score 0):

Although this article is very old: There's a manual how to enter without carnet to Iran
http://travel.s1ck.ch/desktop/#blog/31/164/2014/09/entering-iran-without-carnet-de-passage.html